# RAW images not supported in Aperture after Time Machine restore

Tags: time-machine, aperture

After restoring from a Time Machine Backup all of the RAW images in my aperture library show as "Not supported", even though they did work on my old laptop (where the backup was made).

Here is what I tried:

- Downloading and manually installing the latest Camera RAW
- Repairing permissions for my Aperture Library
- Repairing the Aperture Library itself
- Rebuilding the library itself

And it still says "File type not supported"  The weird thing is after I rebuild or repair the database, the thumbnail will work, But expanding will then break it and all of the thumbnails will go back to the exclamation mark.

I have multiple backups, one time machine and one put on a windows server.

My camera is supported by [Digital Camera RAW](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5371) - Sony Alpha SLT-A57

Comment: So, did you try restoring from your Windows server backup? Did you get the same results? Also, are the images viewable in other Mac applications like Preview or Quicklook in Finder? RAW files are handled by the OS X system so either there is a specific problem with Aperture, or your files are corrupted in some kind... You could also try to load them on a Windows system with specific Sony RAW drivers to see if at least they can be recovered on another system...

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the files are completely corrupted.  I'll try restoring from the Windows Server backup like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this problem isn't with Aperture at all as the image files themselves are corrupt.  This isn't the solution to the problem, because this is just a side-effect of the main problem.